# The default FormLayoutFunction

Tags: output-formatting, customization, wolfram-cloud, form-building

`FormLayoutFunction` allows you to specify a custom layout for form's items.

But what if you want to only slight fix the default layout? It is not so clear what is the default value of this option so one needs to assemble it themselves, which is not a trivial task considering all related blocks like labels/controllers/tooltips/validation etc.

Knowing the default `FormLayoutFunction` would help a lot. Does anyone know this / is willing to read the source code to extract it?

Comment: Check out ``Forms`buildLayoutFunction`` which seems to be how the first argument is parsed out as well as ``Forms`PackageScope`synthetizeLayoutFunction``. How this appears to be converted to HTML inside ``Templating`ToHTML`` is via ``Forms`doLayout``